# java.io.NotSerializableException With Java 8/Jetty 9 Compat App Engine Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, jetty-9

When attempting to upload a file to a Google App Engine Application running in the Java 8/Jetty 9 Compatible Managed VM environment, I get the following stack trace because the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser$MultiPart` class does NOT implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.

I get the following exception:

```
[INFO] java.io.NotSerializableException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser$MultiPart
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
[INFO]  at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
[INFO]  at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
[INFO]  at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
[INFO]  at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
[INFO]  at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.writeObject(Collections.java:2691)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
[INFO]  at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
[INFO]  at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.serialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:28)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.DatastoreSessionStore.createEntityForSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:73)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.DatastoreSessionStore.saveSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:112)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SessionManager$AppEngineSession.save(SessionManager.java:145)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.jetty9.VmRuntimeWebAppContext.doScope(VmRuntimeWebAppContext.java:299)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you see there:

```
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.serialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:28)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.DatastoreSessionStore.createEntityForSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:73)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.DatastoreSessionStore.saveSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:112)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SessionManager$AppEngineSession.save(SessionManager.java:145)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:43)
```

server is trying to put `MultiPartInputStreamParser` into user Session (and save to database). You shouldn't do that.

Comment: My apologies.  

I know why the problem is happening - the App Engine runtime puts ALL session variables into the datastore.  

I don't think it is _unreasonable_ to assume that javax.servlet.http.Part _should not_ be stored in memory. I have a managed bean that is `@ViewScoped`, so the contents of the bean will stay _in memory_ so long as the client is accessing the page.

Comment: each app engine instance is stateless. to make state it must share state with every other instance in the cluster, so everything related to user state/session must be stored in database. basically you shouldn't keep anything in memory on app engine, it doesn't work this way

Comment: The Google App Engine framework provides a `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>` property setting in the `appengine-web.xml` configuration file.  The `javax.servlet.http.Part` is a standard facet of the Servlet API and the JSF 2.2 framework finally provides a `<h:inputFile>` tag.  The App Engine platform is fantastic and the main reason I'm publishing this question is to ensure the people that are trying to do the same thing are able to find a solution.  Ultimately, the answer should contain a viable work-around that will allow someone to use the `h:inputFile` JSF tag on App Engine apps.

Comment: then you probably need to ask another question, this one is not about _"how to avoid using sessions by `h:inputFile`" tag_.